# A genetic disease that is characterised by both gigantism and intellectual disability

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, genetics, diseases, health

In an *Of Mice and Men* parody I want to write, *Of Rats and Women*, there is a 30 years old woman named Léonie Petit (her surname is ironic, because *petit* is a French adjective that means small/little/short/petite, and she is a tall person) (she is a Lennie Small expy) (an expy is an exported character) that has the following features:

1. Léonie Petit has proportional gigantism: she is 2.04 meters tall.
2. She has a deep nasally voice (she sounds like Jessica Darrow, Luisa Madrigal's voice actress from Lin-Manuel Miranda's *Encanto* if she had nose cancer).
3. Petit has elongated facial features.
4. She is described to be as smart as a dog (that means she is mildly intellectually disabled) (to be exact, Petit has high emotional, and naturalistic intelligences, but low mathematical, and linguistic intelligences) (Léonie Petit talks like the Hulk from Disney's Marvel Multiverse, in other words, she talks in the third singular person without conjugating).

So, I wonder of there is a real life genetic disease characterised by both proportional gigantism and intellectual disability?

Comment: One question per question please.  The last 3 paragraphs could be reduced to:  "If such a disease exists then I would be interested in the mode of inheritance and chromosome-related characteristics" rather than listing all of the possibilities, especially since these should be readily available once you have the name of a disease.  Note also that a diagnosis of dyspraxia is only reached in the absence of other neurological impairments, so if the character has some genetic disease that impacts intellect then by definition she won't be said to have dyspraxia.

Comment: (a) Consider [Sotos Syndrome](https://rarediseases.org/rare-diseases/sotos-syndrome/). (b) -1 for poor research (I found that in 30 seconds via Google). (c) Please note that while it looks like we're a free research service, we're not. Our goal is to help you develop and consistently use the rules of an imaginary world of your own creation. You're asking for a Real World illness for what appears to be a Real World application. That's not what we do. So VTC as Not About Worldbuilding.

Comment: Also VTC. This is not about building a world; if it were the OP could clearly just make up a plausible sounding disease. This is looking for a real-world justification in the real world for a fictional character, to add realism. As @JBH says, we are not a free research service. Try a search engine. Look for genetic diseases similar to the one's you already know.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need to have one disease to be both silly and tall. You can just be tall -[some women just reach that height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isis_the_Amazon)- and suffer from underdevelopped brain, or have two diseases, one for each trait.

Answer (score 1):

**Make it up**

You are better off inventing a suitable condition or simply not referring to the name of the condition in universe. The story will not suffer if you omit the discussion about what chromosome carries the condition.

Using a real disorder, the best case scenario is you find some niche developmental disorder that fits your character, but is unfamiliar to most people. Those people won't care that you used a real disorder and not a made up one.

Then there is the minute fraction of people who have this disorder. Unless you are prepared to become the world expert on Wyck Syndrome. Those people  and their families will be upset that you portrayed their disorder inaccurately or played it for laughs.